# Collapsible table does not work in IE BUT works in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, dropdown, collapsable

The below code works perfectly in Chrome however it does not render properly in Internet Explorer (any version). can you please help. None of the buttons work and the table does not open or close in IE.

Hi
The below code works perfectly in Chrome however it does not render properly in Internet Explorer (any version). can you please help. None of the buttons work and the table does not open or close in IE.

```js
        (function () {
            const headings = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(headings, h => {
                let btn = h.querySelector('button');
                let target = h.nextElementSibling;

                btn.onclick = () => {
                    let expanded = btn.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';

                    btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
                    target.hidden = expanded;
                }
            });
        })()
```

```css
<style>
        body {
          
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        main {
            border-width: 1px 0;
            border-style: solid;
        }

            main h2 {
                margin: 0;
            }

            main > div + h2 {
                border-top: 1px solid;
            }

        h2 button {
            all: inherit;
            border: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0.5em 0;
        }
                 

        button svg {
            height: 1em;
            margin-left: 0.5em;
        }

        [aria-expanded="true"] .vert {
            display: none;
        }

        [aria-expanded] rect {
            fill: currentColor;
        }

    
    </style>
```

```html
 <main style="width:50%; margin:auto">
        <h2>
            <button aria-expanded="false">
                <div style="font-size:15px"> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</div>
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                    <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4" />
                    <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div hidden>

            <li>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

            <li>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

            <li>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

            <li>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

            <li>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

        </div>
        <h2>
            <button aria-expanded="false">
                <div style="font-size:15px"> How To Use </div>
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                    <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4" />
                    <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div hidden>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />

                <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold"> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</div>
               Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />

                <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold"> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</div>

               Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />


                <span style="font-weight:bold">Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />


                <span style="font-weight:bold">Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />


                <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold">  Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text </div>

                Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />


                <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold">Mix with Concealer or Contour</div>

                Mix 1 - 3 drops of PureOne Elixir with your cream concealer/ contour prior to your make up application, then apply with either a beauty sponge or brush for a flawless and radiant skin finish. Tip: When using a liquid concealer/contour it is advised to only apply PureOne Elixir to your beauty sponge or brush.
                <br />
                <br />


                <span style="font-weight:bold">Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text:</span> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
                <br />
                <br />


                <span style="font-weight:bold">Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</span>Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <button aria-expanded="false">
                <div style="font-size:15px"> Caution </div>
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                    <rect class="vert" height="8" width="2" y="1" x="4" />
                    <rect height="2" width="8" y="4" x="1" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div hidden>
            <p>
                <li> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.</li>

                <li> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>

                <li> Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text Text</li>
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel. what do I put into Caniuse search bar to determine the issue?

Comment: @RachelGallen _“if you check caniuse.com, the button input is not supported in IE (only in html4)”_ - what are you talking about? IE has no problem with the `button` element (at least if you are not using a totally outdated version.) Can you please link directly to the section you are referring to?

Comment: What IE still _doesn’t_ support, is ES6 stuff like arrow functions, https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions So unless this gets transpiled to “normal” JavaScript, of course this won’t work in IE. Did you not bother to check the console for errors?

Comment: @CBroe im very new to coding so will need some support on how to overcome this issue. what would i need to do to? do i replace the => or add some code to support it to work?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/en/repl can help you convert it to “normal” JavaScript automatically.